Cross-Compile ROS2 Jazzy for ARM-HF on Ubuntu AMD-64 using Docker
Overview
I have been attempting to cross-compile the base components of ROS2 Jazzy for ARM-HF for a few days now with no luck. I successfully created a dockerfile and ran docker build --platform linux/armhf to cross-compile via docker emulation and then copied the install directory to the embedded target and everything worked as expected. However, emulation take 5-6 hours for compilation, which isn't conducive to speedy development (i.e., when we wish to remove or alter ros2-base packages).
Unfortunately, the cross-compile tool and documentation appears to be deprecated since Humble. Also, we do not wish to run docker engine on the ARM-HF SOM due to CPU and RAM constraints, we wish to squeeze as much performance as we can and running additional processes is not feasible.
So, I would appreciate any input you can provide on this to help me cross-compile ROS2 Jazzy Base components, without using Docker emulation. I have provided a detailed account what I have done so far in the section below if wish to reproduce results. Let me know if anything looks foolish that could be causing my issue.
Thanks in advance!
Cross-Compilation Attempt (Fails)
I have been trying to cross-compile in a AMD64 docker image for ARM-HF using the gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf and g++-arm-linux-gnueabihf cross-compilation tools.
My cross-compilation process is as follows.

Create a Debian Bookworm ARM-HF docker image (via emulation) with all the ros2 build dependencies (effectively same as the cross-compilation emulation image just without the colcon build step).
Create a Debian Bookworm AMD-64 docker image with ros-dev tools and mount/copy the ARM-HF file system onto this AMD-64 image.
Run the AMD-64 docker image and invoke colcon build command with an appropriate ARM-HF CMake Toolchain file (e.g., setting CMAKE_SYSROOT and CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH).

Machines / Docker Images

Development Machine: Ubuntu 22.04 AMD64
Host Docker Image: Debian Bookworm AMD64
Target Docker Image: Debian Bookworm ARM-HF

Development Machine Setup

Install docker engine (Docker version 27.1.2, build d01f264)
Add ROS2 GPG Key and Apt Source List, as per instructions here
Install ros-dev-tools and rosinstall generator sudo apt install ros-dev-tools python3-rosinstall-generator
Clone ros2 jazzy base components and create text file containing list of ros2 build dependency:

mkdir ros2_jazzy/src && cd ros2_jazzy
rosinstall_generator ros_base --rosdistro jazzy --deps | vcs import src
rosdep install --reinstall --simulate --from-paths src --ignore-src --skip-keys "fastcdr rti-connext-dds-6.0.1 urdfdom_headers" \ | sed "s/sudo -H apt-get/apt-get -y/g" | sed "s/^ *//g" | sed "/#/d" | sort \ | tee ros_build.deps



Dockerfile and Docker Image Creation
Created image using command docker build --tag test-ros-base --target ros-base . using following dockerfile.
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1

# ARGUMENTS
ARG DEBIAN_DIST=bookworm
ARG ROS2_DIST=jazzy

#############################
# ROS-SYSTEM-ROOT IMAGE (ARM-HF)  
#############################
FROM --platform=linux/armhf debian:${DEBIAN_DIST} AS ros-sysroot-armhf
ARG DEBIAN_DIST
ARG ROS2_DIST

# Install curl
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get upgrade -y && \
    apt-get install -y curl

# Add ROS2 GPG Key and Source List
RUN apt-get update && curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/ros.key -o /usr/share/keyrings/ros-archive-keyring.gpg && \
    echo "deb [arch=armhf signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/ros-archive-keyring.gpg] http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu ${DEBIAN_DIST} main" \
    | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros2.list

# apt update and upgrade
RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade

# Install ROS Build Dependencies
RUN --mount=type=bind,source=ros2_${ROS2_DIST},target=/ros2_${ROS2_DIST} \
    ./ros2_${ROS2_DIST}/ros_build.deps


#############################
# ROS-BASE IMAGE  
#############################
# I know bad practice to write --platform=linux/amd64
# this is only for testing purposes
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 debian:${DEBIAN_DIST} AS ros-base
ARG DEBIAN_DIST

COPY --from=ros-sysroot-armhf / /opt/armhf/sysroot

# Install ARM-HF compiler
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get upgrade -y && \
    apt-get install -y curl gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf g++-arm-linux-gnueabihf

# Add ROS2 GPG Key and Source List
RUN apt-get update && curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/ros.key -o /usr/share/keyrings/ros-archive-keyring.gpg && \
    echo "deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/ros-archive-keyring.gpg] http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu ${DEBIAN_DIST} main" \
    | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros2.list

RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade && apt-get install -y ros-dev-tools pkg-config

ARM-HF CMake Toolchain File
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME       Linux)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR  arm)

set(TARGET_TRIPLET      arm-linux-gnueabihf)

set(CMAKE_SYSROOT           "/opt/armhf/sysroot/")
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH    "/opt/armhf/sysroot/")

# Compiler Binaries
set(CMAKE_AR            /usr/bin/${TARGET_TRIPLET}-ar)
set(CMAKE_ASM_COMPILER  /usr/bin/${TARGET_TRIPLET}-gcc)
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER    /usr/bin/${TARGET_TRIPLET}-gcc)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER  /usr/bin/${TARGET_TRIPLET}-g++)
set(CMAKE_LINKER        /usr/bin/${TARGET_TRIPLET}-ld)
set(CMAKE_OBJCOPY   /usr/bin/${TARGET_TRIPLET}-objcopy CACHE INTERNAL "")
set(CMAKE_RANLIB        /usr/bin/${TARGET_TRIPLET}-ranlib CACHE INTERNAL "")
set(CMAKE_SIZE      /usr/bin/${TARGET_TRIPLET}-size CACHE INTERNAL "")
set(CMAKE_STRIP         /usr/bin/${TARGET_TRIPLET}-strp CACHE INTERNAL "")

set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PACKAGE ONLY)

set(ENV{PKG_CONFIG_PATH} "${CMAKE_SYSROOT}/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/pkgconfig")
set(ENV{PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR} "${CMAKE_SYSROOT}/usr/lib/pkgconfig:${CMAKE_SYSROOT}/usr/share/pkgconfig")
set(ENV{PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR} ${CMAKE_SYSROOT})

Cross-Compilation Attempt
On host machine start docker AMD-64 image and mount the ros2_jazzy folder within the ARM-HF sysroot folder that was mounted/copied to the AMD-64 docker image:

docker run -v ~<path-to-ros2_jazzy-dir>:/opt/armhf/sysroot/ros2_jazzy:rw -it armhf-build-test

In the interactive docker container running I do the following:

cd /opt/armhf/sysroot/ros2_jazzy
colcon build --cmake-force-configure --cmake-args -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=<path-to-armhf-toolchain-file>

Unfortunately when I do this, I have received error after error which I have slowly been solving, such ash the pkg-config variables within the toolchain file. However, I now have ended up with a library linking error, provided below. KDL Parser cannot find the the URDF library built as part of the project.
Library Linking Error
Only snippet of output log due to character constraint
[0.113s] -- The C compiler identification is GNU 12.2.0
[0.161s] -- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 12.2.0
[0.168s] -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
[0.226s] -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
[0.231s] -- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc - skipped
[0.231s] -- Detecting C compile features
[0.231s] -- Detecting C compile features - done
[0.233s] -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
[0.302s] -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
[0.309s] -- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ - skipped
[0.309s] -- Detecting CXX compile features
[0.310s] -- Detecting CXX compile features - done
[0.312s] -- Found ament_cmake_ros: 0.12.0 (/opt/armhf/sysroot/data/ros2_jazzy/install/ament_cmake_ros/share/ament_cmake_ros/cmake)
[0.527s] -- Found Python3: /usr/bin/python3 (found version "3.11.2") found components: Interpreter 
[0.620s] -- Found orocos_kdl_vendor: 0.5.1 (/opt/armhf/sysroot/data/ros2_jazzy/install/orocos_kdl_vendor/share/orocos_kdl_vendor/cmake)
[0.635s] -- Found eigen3_cmake_module: 0.3.0 (/opt/armhf/sysroot/data/ros2_jazzy/install/eigen3_cmake_module/share/eigen3_cmake_module/cmake)
[0.636s] -- Found Eigen3: TRUE (found version "3.4.0") 
[0.636s] -- Ensuring Eigen3 include directory is part of orocos-kdl CMake target
[0.638s] -- Found urdf: 2.10.0 (/opt/armhf/sysroot/data/ros2_jazzy/install/urdf/share/urdf/cmake)
[0.667s] -- Found TinyXML2 via Config file: /opt/armhf/sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/cmake/tinyxml2
[0.679s] -- Found ament_lint_auto: 0.17.1 (/opt/armhf/sysroot/data/ros2_jazzy/install/ament_lint_auto/share/ament_lint_auto/cmake)
[0.760s] -- Found gtest sources under '/opt/armhf/sysroot/data/ros2_jazzy/install/gtest_vendor/src/gtest_vendor': C++ tests using 'Google Test' will be built
[0.761s] -- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD
[0.826s] -- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD - Success
[0.826s] -- Found Threads: TRUE  
[0.830s] -- Added test 'copyright' to check source files copyright and LICENSE
[0.833s] -- Added test 'cppcheck' to perform static code analysis on C / C++ code
[0.833s] -- Configured cppcheck include dirs: $<BUILD_INTERFACE:/opt/armhf/sysroot/data/ros2_jazzy/src/kdl_parser/include>
[0.833s] -- Configured cppcheck exclude dirs and/or files: 
[0.836s] -- Added test 'cpplint' to check C / C++ code against the Google style
[0.836s] -- Configured cpplint exclude dirs and/or files: 
[0.838s] -- Added test 'lint_cmake' to check CMake code style
[0.841s] -- Added test 'uncrustify' to check C / C++ code style
[0.841s] -- Configured uncrustify additional arguments: 
[0.842s] -- Added test 'xmllint' to check XML markup files
[0.844s] -- Configuring done
[0.852s] -- Generating done
[0.854s] -- Build files have been written to: /opt/armhf/sysroot/data/ros2_jazzy/build/kdl_parser

...

[5.158s] [ 90%] [32m[1mLinking CXX executable test_kdl_parser[0m
[5.225s] /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/12/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: warning: libament_index_cpp.so, needed by /opt/armhf/sysroot/data/ros2_jazzy/install/urdf/lib/liburdf.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
[5.225s] /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/12/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: warning: libclass_loader.so, needed by /opt/armhf/sysroot/data/ros2_jazzy/install/urdf/lib/liburdf.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
[5.225s] /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/12/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: warning: librcpputils.so, needed by /opt/armhf/sysroot/data/ros2_jazzy/install/urdf/lib/liburdf.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
[5.282s] /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/12/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /opt/armhf/sysroot/data/ros2_jazzy/install/urdf/lib/liburdf.so: undefined reference to `class_loader::ClassLoader::getLibraryPath[abi:cxx11]() const'
[5.282s] /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/12/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /opt/armhf/sysroot/data/ros2_jazzy/install/urdf/lib/liburdf.so: undefined reference to `class_loader::MultiLibraryClassLoader::loadLibrary(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
[5.282s] /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/12/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /opt/armhf/sysroot/data/ros2_jazzy/install/urdf/lib/liburdf.so: undefined reference to `class_loader::MultiLibraryClassLoader::MultiLibraryClassLoader(bool)'
[5.283s] /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/12/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /opt/armhf/sysroot/data/ros2_jazzy/install/urdf/lib/liburdf.so: undefined reference to `class_loader::impl::getPluginBaseToFactoryMapMapMutex()'
[5.284s] /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/12/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /opt/armhf/sysroot/data/ros2_jazzy/install/urdf/lib/liburdf.so: undefined reference to `ament_index_cpp::get_package_prefix(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
[5.284s] /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/12/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /opt/armhf/sysroot/data/ros2_jazzy/install/urdf/lib/liburdf.so: undefined reference to `class_loader::ClassLoader::isLibraryLoaded() const'
[5.285s] /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/12/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /opt/armhf/sysroot/data/ros2_jazzy/install/urdf/lib/liburdf.so: undefined reference to `class_loader::ClassLoader::hasUnmanagedInstanceBeenCreated()'
[5.285s] /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/12/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /opt/armhf/sysroot/data/ros2_jazzy/install/urdf/lib/liburdf.so: undefined reference to `rcpputils::get_platform_library_name(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, bool)'
[5.285s] /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/12/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /opt/armhf/sysroot/data/ros2_jazzy/install/urdf/lib/liburdf.so: undefined reference to `class_loader::ClassLoader::isOnDemandLoadUnloadEnabled() const'
[5.286s] /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/12/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /opt/armhf/sysroot/data/ros2_jazzy/install/urdf/lib/liburdf.so: undefined reference to `class_loader::ClassLoader::unloadLibraryInternal(bool)'
[5.286s] /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/12/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /opt/armhf/sysroot/data/ros2_jazzy/install/urdf/lib/liburdf.so: undefined reference to `class_loader::MultiLibraryClassLoader::unloadLibrary(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
[5.287s] /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/12/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /opt/armhf/sysroot/data/ros2_jazzy/install/urdf/lib/liburdf.so: undefined reference to `class_loader::MultiLibraryClassLoader::getAllAvailableClassLoaders() const'
[5.287s] /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/12/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /opt/armhf/sysroot/data/ros2_jazzy/install/urdf/lib/liburdf.so: undefined reference to `ament_index_cpp::get_resources(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
[5.287s] /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/12/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /opt/armhf/sysroot/data/ros2_jazzy/install/urdf/lib/liburdf.so: undefined reference to `class_loader::ClassLoader::setUnmanagedInstanceBeenCreated(bool)'
[5.288s] /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/12/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /opt/armhf/sysroot/data/ros2_jazzy/install/urdf/lib/liburdf.so: undefined reference to `class_loader::impl::getFactoryMapForBaseClass(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
[5.288s] /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/12/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /opt/armhf/sysroot/data/ros2_jazzy/install/urdf/lib/liburdf.so: undefined reference to `ament_index_cpp::get_resource(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >*)'
[5.289s] /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/12/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /opt/armhf/sysroot/data/ros2_jazzy/install/urdf/lib/liburdf.so: undefined reference to `class_loader::impl::AbstractMetaObjectBase::isOwnedBy(class_loader::ClassLoader const*) const'
[5.289s] /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/12/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /opt/armhf/sysroot/data/ros2_jazzy/install/urdf/lib/liburdf.so: undefined reference to `class_loader::MultiLibraryClassLoader::~MultiLibraryClassLoader()'
[5.289s] /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/12/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /opt/armhf/sysroot/data/ros2_jazzy/install/urdf/lib/liburdf.so: undefined reference to `class_loader::ClassLoader::loadLibrary()'
[5.289s] /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/12/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /opt/armhf/sysroot/data/ros2_jazzy/install/urdf/lib/liburdf.so: undefined reference to `typeinfo for ament_index_cpp::PackageNotFoundError'
[5.290s] /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/12/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /opt/armhf/sysroot/data/ros2_jazzy/install/urdf/lib/liburdf.so: undefined reference to `class_loader::MultiLibraryClassLoader::getRegisteredLibraries[abi:cxx11]() const'
[5.295s] collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

It suggests it the URDF library cannot find various libraries needed by it. I can fix this error by modifying the kdl_parser CMakeLists.txt file to include the following lines (added lines indicated by a +, original file here).
find_package(ament_cmake_ros REQUIRED)
find_package(orocos_kdl_vendor REQUIRED)
find_package(orocos_kdl REQUIRED)
find_package(urdf REQUIRED)
find_package(urdfdom_headers REQUIRED)
find_package(rcutils REQUIRED)
+find_package(rcpputils REQUIRED)
+find_package(ament_index_cpp REQUIRED)
+find_package(class_loader REQUIRED)

# Default to C++17
if(NOT CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD)
  set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
  set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
endif()

add_library(
  ${PROJECT_NAME}
  src/kdl_parser.cpp)
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC
  "$<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include>"
  "$<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include/${PROJECT_NAME}>"
)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC
  orocos-kdl
  urdfdom_headers::urdfdom_headers)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE
  rcutils::rcutils
  urdf::urdf
  +rcpputils::rcpputils
  +ament_index_cpp::ament_index_cpp
  +class_loader::class_loader)

However, these modifications are not required when building from source on say a Ubuntu machine natively without docker, or when building from source on a docker Debian image with a AMD-64 or ARM-HF architecture. So there is something else missing.
Questions

What am I missing in the toolchain file?
Should I be mounting the ros2_jazzy folder within the target sysroot directory (e.g., /opt/armh/sysroot/ros2_jazzy)? Or should I be placing it in the host root (e.g., /ros2_jazzy directly)?


The liburdf.so object depends on librcpputils, as suggested by the warning. So when the liburdf.so target is exported, it somehow loses the linking. I believe this could be to do with CMAKE_SYSROOT within the toolchain scrubbing the paths on installation, as per the [documentation[(https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_SYSROOT.html).
